# How to fix firefox stop javascript when not responding

Tags: javascript, firefox, automation

I'm currently create a javascript that run a loop forever. However, after a few hours my script stop working, it asks me to continue or stop script. Is there anyway to fix this or use some automation tools to restart firefox and run the javascript again. Because most of time I away from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the long running javascript prompt, you need to occasionally let javascript process other events.   The classic way to do this is like this is using `setTimeout()`.

```
function doNextChunkOfWork() {

    // do some work here

    if (moreWorkToDo) {
        setTimeout(doNextChunkofWork, 1);
    }
}
```

Using the `setTimeout()` lets the javascript engine get back to its event queue and process other events and thus prevents the long running script warning.

---

If you explained what you're really trying to do, we might be able to suggest even better options.  If you're doing some sort of infinite loop, javascript in a browser is meant to be an event-driven environment where the usual mechanism is to create event handlers and let events trigger code to run.  It is not meant for infinite loops polling for something.

Answer (score 0):

id strongly recommend not using any kind of infinite loop - doing so would be just asking for trouble. instead you want to look into using javascript's `setTimeout()` and/or `setInterval()` functions... allowing you to specify a block of code to run every X milliseconds

you can find the docs here

[setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)